# Rails Equipment/Assets/Inventory Modelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a system to track assets and have a problem modelling it.
Basically, the problem arises from the fact, that all the assets have some common attributes (like inventoryID, purchaseDate, Notes, Location etc...), and their own attributes (depending on the detail level we are going to go). So, for example we have printers and computers - obviously they have common and specific attributes.

I am now scratching my head how to approach the modelling of this relationships and to optimize it as much as possible.

STI is too messy for this and not even considered.
What are my other options?
I am researching how to do it with polymorphic associations, but i am not sure it is the right way to do it.

I was thinking in something like:

```
Inventory has_many: :computers, as: :asset (common attributes)
Inventory has_many: :printers, as: :asset (common attributes)

Computer belongs_to: :asset, polymorphic (specific attributes)
Printer  belongs_to: :asset, polymorphic (specific attributes)
```

Something along this way...

I am not sure if this is even possible, seems murky to me.
So, what would be the best way?

Comment: Why is STI messy? It's the a good approach for your problem, in my opinion. STI is very simple in Rails.

Comment: I see it messy because of the N unused fields on N records. When there is  a large amount of data, isn't it better to separate it into additional tables?

Comment: Yes, if there are many different fields, STI is not the best option. But if deviation between models is not too large STI is great.

Comment: I didn't quite get your comment on my answer. Do you still have problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach your problem.

1. The first one is [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html), as you mentioned. It's not bad, if there are relatively few type of "assets" and they don't deviate largely from base object. And it's already included into Rails. Still, as you say, it's not an acceptable approach.
2. The second way is to use MTI (multi table inheritance). In this approach we have one basic table (with shared fields) and subclass tables are related to this main table. You can use [active_record-acts_as](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) gem for this, which makes using MTI dead simple.
3. There is one more approach. By using schemaless databases, which can create fields "on the fly". For instance, by using [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org) gem (which works with MongoDB), you can easily extend your models. More details [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/#inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. MTI looks promising, but I do have another related question, though. What I would like to achieve is to be able to add new asset where i would say it is of type computer while still seperating data into tables. With mentioned MTI gem, i see i can create type of product which will automatically create parent product, too.
How would i approach dynamic form like i would like it have?